# Recommended locations for Windows desktop applications

Tags: windows-installer

We are planning an installation package for Windows 7 and newer. Since the software can also run on Linux, my colleague wants to create a Linux installation package and asked me about what files need to be installed, what their locations are on Windows and what is the guideline for file locations on Windows.

He mentioned that in Linux there is a recommended location for every file type, f.e. /var/log for log files etc.

I told him that I know that 64-bit applications go to c:\Program Files etc. and user specific application data to %appdata%\OurCompany\OurSoftware

I don't have any sources on this, though.

Question:
is there any Microsoft guideline for structuring application installation and what directories to use for application data per-user/per-machine/read-only etc. similar to Linux https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard ?

Comment: You don't need a guideline when you guessed correctly.

Comment: https://www.scribd.com/document/48246732/Windows-File-System-Namespace-Usage-Guidelines

Comment: Well, I maybe guessed two directories correctly but I think there are more ;-) Shared files, read-only configuration, read/write configuration etc. etc. Thanks for the link, that is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately there is no update for Windows 10 but I guess there have not been too many changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a list of links to the recommendations.

Windows Installer Best Practices:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb204770.aspx

Windows Installer and Logo Requirements contains more guidelines:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa372825.aspx

Certification Guidelines is what contains the recommendations for destination folders, in section 10, but the rest of it is useful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt674655(v=vs.85).aspx

I think it's fair to say that very few installs or apps adhere to all of this, but they're not just random rules. They are intended to get you a reliable, maintainable, secure product and installation.